# Nested For of Loop Inside If Statement Only retains last value

Tags: javascript, angular, ecmascript-6, closures, nested-loops

I am having the weirdest issue with my nested for loop inside an Angular service. I have a service in which I am running the below `forEach` function with the data coming back from the service.

```
someArr.forEach(elem => {
 //do something with elem
    if(elem['users'].length >= 1) {
      for (let user of elem['users']) {
        console.log('>>> ', user['firstName'])
        elem['userFirstName'] = user['firstName'];
        elem['userLastName'] = user['lastName'];
        this.tempArr.push(elem);
      }
    } else {
       this.tempArr.push(elem);
    }
  })
```

The `console.log` is logging out the correct first and last name from the inner for loop, but only the last value is pushed to the `tempArr`. I thought using the **let** word resolves this closure issue. What am I missing here?

Comment: can you share `someArr` data?

Comment: Can you add details on the array? what kind of array is it?

Comment: I don't see a closure here, inside the `for` loop you will be modifying the same `elem` reference everytime so you feel that last value is getting pushed. Make a copy of your object, modify and push that copy instead

Comment: Are you seeing multiple copies of the “last element” in your array? If so, that is because you are reassigning the properties of `elem`, so all references to it are being changed with every reassignment.

Comment: It is not so simple. Yes, he/she is doing something fishy inside of the inner for-loop but the outer one is still looping through array of different elements so it might not be the reason.

Comment: the user array contains a user object with first and last name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't pushing a new object just another reference to the same one that you then mutate, when you push use `Object.assign({}, elem)` to create a new object.

Comment: Ah yes this make sense. Thank you @Colby

Comment: other sintax is using the spread operator: this.tempArray.push({...element})